# Force specific letter for usb drive in /dev/sd*

Tags: usb

Is there a way to force an usb drive to always get a specific letter in /dev/sd*?
I know about udev symlinks, that does not help.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. I have a USB3 JBOD with 4 drives in it running zfs. Every time I offline a disk, to hotswap it, it comes back online with a new /dev/sd? device... F*cking annoying. I got a UDEV rule working to use the drive serial numbers to do device symlinks, but it still doesn't play nice with zfs...

Answer (score 1):

You need a [custom UDEV rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd) to set this up. Plug the device in and you can find out the vendorid and productid with ...

```
lsusb
```

this will show several lines that look something like this...

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04fc:0c25 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd
```

From this you can see that ...

- Vendorid is `04fc`
- Productid is `0c25`

As the device is a storage device we will be writing the rule in `60-persistent-storage.rules`. So open this file with your prefered editor (for instance `sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`) and add the following line:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]",SYSFS{idVendor}=="04fc",SYSFS{idProduct}=="0c25", SYMLINK+="usbdrive"
```

This informs udev-manager, that if any storage device with vendorid 04fc and productid 0c25 is plugged into the system to add a symlink in `/dev` with name `usbdrive`. I used `usbdrive` but you can use another name if need be.

From now on you can access this drive with `/dev/usbdrive`.

<sub>I used this [Source](http://howtoxyz.blogspot.com/2008/07/writing-udev-rules.html) for the example.</sub>

Comment: As said in the question, symlinking is not what I want to do.

Comment: udev IS the way to do this but you are welcome to wait for someone else to come up with another method. Doubt it though :)